# app termination error due to NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I get this error every time I want to load a specific UIViewController

> 2016-04-09 20:48:02.183 myApp[91268:15399441] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key registerAction.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aaa6d85 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010c84adeb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010aaa69c9 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x000000010ae7819b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   288   4   UIKit                               0x000000010b461d0c
>   -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88     5   UIKit                               0x000000010b6987fb -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109   6
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9e0890 -[NSArray
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224    7   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010b6971de -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864  8
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010b4688d6
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381   9   UIKit                               0x000000010b469202 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178   10  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010b469560 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138   11 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010b469cd3
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     12  UIKit                               0x000000010b33ffb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] +
>   61    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b34069d
>   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282  14  UIKit                               0x000000010b352180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42   15  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010b2c6ed9 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131   16  UIKit                               0x000000010b2cd568
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769   17  UIKit                               0x000000010b2ca714
>   -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e6db8c8
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24     19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e6db741
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178  20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e6dbaca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9cc301
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9c222c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9c16e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867     24  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010a9c10f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     25  UIKit
>   0x000000010b2c9f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402    26  UIKit
>   0x000000010b2cef09 UIApplicationMain + 171    27  myApp
>   0x000000010a70dfb2 main + 114     28  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010dc6292d start + 1  29  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

the content inside the UIViewController ==>

```
import UIKit

class signUpPage: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var passTextField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.viewDidLoad()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    self.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func registerAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let email = self.emailTextField.text
    let pass = self.passTextField.text
    if (email != "" && pass != ""){

        firebase_ref.createUser(email, password: pass, withValueCompletionBlock: { (error, results) in
            if (error == nil ){
                firebase_ref.authUser(email, password: pass, withCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) in
                    if (error == nil ){
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")
                        print("Account created Successfully ")
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }else{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            }else{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })


    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter an email and password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func cancleAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )
}
```

}
Thanks in advance for your help  :)

Comment: I've defined only 2 of them and I've used them both XD 
1.emailTextField 2.passTextField
@El Captain

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the IBAction registerAction connected to your xib.

Go to your xib for this UIViewController, control-click and drag from the button to File's Owner and you'll see a menu pop up with a list of your IBActions.  Can select the correct one from the list to connect the button too.

Also if you may want to define the sender as a type instead of AnyObject.

[image]

Or you don't have the correct class connected to the xib

Click on File's Owner and make sure the correct class is in Identity Inspector:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

class signUpPage: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var passTextField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
self.viewDidLoad()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
self.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func registerAction(sender: AnyObject) {
let email = self.emailTextField.text
let pass = self.passTextField.text
if (email != "" && pass != ""){

    firebase_ref.createUser(email, password: pass, withValueCompletionBlock: { (error, results) in
        if (error == nil ){
            firebase_ref.authUser(email, password: pass, withCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) in
                if (error == nil ){
                    if (authData.uid != nil) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")
}
                    print("Account created Successfully ")
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }else{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }else{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })


}else{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter an email and password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

 @IBAction func cancleAction(sender: AnyObject) {

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )
}
```

Comment: where should I write that code :) @vaibby